# AttributeError: builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'top'

Tags: python, pygame

Here is the code:

```
class Enemies():
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []
        self.number= random.randrange(8)
        self.image= pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Aitor/Desktop/Odin.png")
        self.rect= self.image.get_rect
        self.run_across= 0 #El numero que recorrera la lista

        for x in range(self.number):
            self.list.append(self.rect)
            self.list[self.run_across].top= random.randrange(20,50)
            self.list[self.run_across].left= random.randrange(20,50)
            self.run_across += 1

        self.run_across= 0
```

The error is in: `self.list[self.run_across].top= random.randrange(20,50)`
The code is supposed to save in a list some rects with random dimensions but with the same image. I don't know why it get that error.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()`?  Have you simply missed a function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.rect` is set to a function object:

```
self.rect= self.image.get_rect
```

You subsequently add that to your `list` attribute:

```
for x in range(self.number):
    self.list.append(self.rect)
```

This is the `builtin_function_or_method` type the exception refers to; the method is implemented in C. Perhaps you meant to call it instead?

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Comment: Yes, it was that. Thanks!